# How much precision does a recursive representation of nested functions have

Tags: python, recursion, floating-point

I will use a python example here to make my question more comprehensible:

Take the recursive representation of a nested sine function:

```
def nestedSin(val, amount): ## val in degrees

    if amount == 1:

        return math.sinh(val)

    return math.sinh(nestedSin(val, amount-1))
```

So if I run the function:

```
z = nestedSin(20, 3)
```

I will get:

```
z = math.sinh(math.sinh(math.sinh(20)))
```

My question is...will this compute the first sine function and return it's rounded value (i.e. floating point limitation) and then compute the sine of that returned value etc.?

Or will the floating point limitations only apply to the final returned value of the recursive function?

Basically I am asking if the above is more precise than:

```
x = math.sinh(20)
y = math.sinh(x)
z = math.sinh(y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectively the 3 `sinh` operations are performed consecutively, each with its own rounding; just like your `x y z` example.

So, no, there is no difference; all the methods are equally (in)accurate I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I seemed to have hit a brick wall so. I have a matrix which rotates because it multiplies times a bunch of nested sin functions. Is there no way around this then? I suppose I will have to ask a new question

Comment: The general way around this is to use a library that supports abitrary precision math and then round the final result down to the desired precision. Take a look at http://mpmath.org/

Comment: The more problem specific way around it is to see if you can accumulate a total 'rotation' amount in the same direction, or perform some other kind of mathematical simplification using trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question

> will this compute the first sine function and return it's rounded value (i.e. floating point limitation) and then compute the sine of that returned value etc

function return the first float value and again call `def nestedSin(val, amount)` function with latest with rounded value and call it again and when out of range it will raise

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

so both examples are same.

[OverflowError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError):-Raised when the result of an arithmetic operation is too large to be represented.